# PHPExcel - colspan the subject name

Tags: php, phpexcel

- Table name: **subject**
  [image]
- My Expected output
  [image]
- My code

  ```
  <?php
      //dbconnection

      $q = "SELECT name FROM subject";
      $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
      {
          $name[] = $row['name'];
      }

      $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

      $headers = array('School Name');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($headers, null, 'A1');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($name, null, 'B1');

      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('B1:C1');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('D1:E1');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('F1:G1');
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('H1:I1');
  ?>
  ```
- I want to set colspan = 2 for each subject. I don't want to write 4 individual lines of code. I try with for loop as below:

  ```
  $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

  $row = 1;
  $highestColumn = $objWorksheet -> getHighestColumn();
  $highestColumn++;

  for($column = 'A'; $column != $highestColumn; $column++)
  {
      if($column <= 'C')
      {
          //[HERE]
      }
  }
  ```
- After I write the for loop, I am stuck. I have no ideas on how to control the column name and set the colspan. Can someone help me?

Comment: if you span a col/row, then the spanned cell's address is the address of the top-left corner of that spanned cell, so if you span B1->C1 to produce a single "two column" cell, the address is still B1, and C1 is hidden/suppressed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably a lot easier to do this in a loop over the subject list:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'School Name');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:A2');

$column = 'B';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.'1', $row['name']);
    $mergeRange = $column.'1:';
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.'2', 'Student Name');
    $column++;
    $mergeRange .= $column.'1';
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.'2', 'Grade');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($mergeRange);
    $column++;
}
```